# Admin group membership not replicated

Tags: windows, active-directory

Currently, my user account is member of *Administrators* and *Domain-Administrators* in a network with two DCs. On both DCs, changes in my group membership will be replicated without problems. However, if i log on to a domain member computer, im not part of the group administrators.

As far as i know, membership in AD group *Administrators* should give you administrative privileges on every domain computer. What could cause this error and how do i solve it?

Furthermore, if i do a `gpresult` (even after some `gpupdate`'s) on the DC, my group membership is correctly listed. If i do it on the member computers, it is not.

TIA, rhavin.

Answer (score 1):

The Domain Admins group, by default, is in the built-in  Administrators group on domain member machines. The Administrators group on a domain controller gives administrative access to the domain controller, and should have Domain Admins as a member of the group by default.

By adding your account to the Domain Admins group in a standard configuration, your account will be given all the rights and privileges that the Domain Admins group has. You won't see your account with a separate entry in the local member machine's Administrators group. You should just see Domain Admins, unless someone is using group policy to add additional groups.

You can learn about the specifics of what each default group does from [Microsoft TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756898(v=WS.10).aspx). Default groups have basically been the same since Server 2003, so this link is still useful.

There are a number of things that could be wrong with network connectivity or group policy enforcement, so take a look at the event logs for errors. If it says anything about not being able to see a domain controller, then you are logging in with cached credentials and the machine is not recognizing the change in group membership.

Once any group policy and network connectivity issues have been resoved, open a command prompt and run "gpupdate /force" to manually get all the latest group policy updates, and reboot the machine if required. This will make sure the local machine gets the right settings from Active Directory that say that you are a member of the Domain Admins group.

To summarize, it sounds like you are doing the right thing by adding the account to Domain Admins. You should not see your name as an admin, just the AD group 'mydomain\domain admins' on the local machine. You need to check network connectivity and group policy for errors if you are still not able to do administrative tasks after rebooting the local machine.